# Can multiple operating systems share profiles and programs?

Tags: filesystems, partition, software-installation, dual-boot, file-management

I'm new to Linux and trying multiple variants of Ubuntu (standard, Mint, Pop, etc.). Unfortunately, every OS is isolated on different partitions, with separate settings, user groups, etc. and programs have to be installed each time I install a new OS. I would like to have a primary OS (Ubuntu LTS) and then all subsequent OS's refer to the primary OS for user profiles, program installations, etc. - Is this possible?

My purpose is twofold: 1) ease of trying new distros without hassling with setup/maintenance of multiple profiles and programs, and 2) save on disk space by reducing duplicate files.

I know how to access files and mount folders between each distro's partition, but is there a way to trick the OS into thinking the primary partition is where it should be looking for everything?

I don't mind trying things that are experimental, as this is a new system and I have no critical data on it yet.

Comment: trying multiple distribution on same disk, sharing a common `/home` (for instance) wouldn't be what I call easy,  specialy if you are new to linux. The other alternative I could think of is *) a main OS with NFS (or samba) exported `/home` dir, *) tested OS on virtual machine, mounting your home dir. however this is marginaly less complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No. You can share user settings easily buy creating a separate partition for `/home` and mounting it in all your used OSes. And if you have different `/home`s you can use symlinks.

however, sharing programs doesn't make any sense whatsoever (different distros may use different versions of applications, so in certain cases **configurations files may be incompatible**), besides most users never touch anything in /etc, so this advice holds.

Comment: Note that this only works for the user profiles. Program installations are far more tricky as they usually will have different versions between the distros and depend on different kernels etc. Sometimes even locations of standard config files are different between major distributions.

Comment: You will also likely have serious problems with basic system libs like `glibc` which are likely to be different versions on the different operating systems. Sharing user settings (i.e. `$HOME`) is fine, but you really, really don't want to be sharing programs.

Comment: Sharing programs doesn't make any sense whatsoever (different distros may use different versions of applications, so in certain cases **configs may be incompatible**), and most users never touch anything in `/etc`, so this advice holds. There's no need to downvote it because it's well thought enough.

Comment: I downvoted. it was because the question asks "Can multiple operating systems share profiles and programs?" and your answer started with "yes" and didn't mention anything about programs. So it could give the idea that sharing programs is fine.